# Review time for IEEE transactions on image processing

Tags: journals, ieee

Apologies if this is not in keeping with ASE, but I wondered if anyone knows? I have a paper I submitted nearly 5 months ago that is still in peer review. I'm not sure if this is an appropriate time to email the editor. Many thanks!

Comment: Reviews for journals like TIP can take a while (5 months is not unusual) - I would leave it a while longer.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Thanks! Any idea what an appropriate time would be? I'm approaching PhD deadline time..

Comment: For one of my papers (at a different transactions journal), the first round review took about 6 months, and the second round review took another 6 months. I'd expect TIP to be around the same. I tend to start emailing them around the 6 month mark, but cautiously to avoid annoying anyone. For what it's worth, journal papers tend to be one of those things that refuse to be rushed.

Comment: Just look on the bottom left of published papers, you will see the time frame for the first, second, .. acceptance results.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question - am about to submit to this journal. Good information in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

LetPub.com states "about 8.1 months" as the average duration of peer review for IEEE Transactions on Image Processing [1](http://www.letpub.com/index.php?journalid=3390&page=journalapp&view=detail).

They claim the "data is from authors," but I do not know how or if they obtain a representative sample.